# How do change a fluid into a mesh?

Tags: physics

I just bought FlipFluids and one of the simulations that i would like to recreate is in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FARyt4s3T7E&t=197s (Minute 3:43). Any suggestions?

Comment: I think that it is just simple transition done with changing alpha value, they filled capsule with fluid and once it was full it dissapeared and the bottle object appeared at the same place

Comment: ahh alright, thank you